# Is there an open source alternative to Windows Volume Shadow Copy

Tags: open-source, shadow-copy, volume-shadow-service

Is there an open source alternative to Windows Volume Shadow Copy?
I need to keep previous versions of files in a directory
automatically without having to use a check in / check out
process or a traditional version control system.
Additionally, the platform I need this on is Windows XP and I've found that the
Windows Volume Shadow Copy is only available on the Server Windows versions.

Comment: Is there a way to configure an open source version control system like git to automatically save a new version when a file changes?

Comment: In UNIX, there's etckeeper that does this. etckeeper is a collection of tools to let /etc be stored in a git, mercurial, darcs, or bzr repository. It hooks into apt (and other package managers including yum and pacman-g2) to automatically commit changes made to /etc during package upgrades. It tracks file metadata that revison control systems do not normally support.

Comment: -1 this question suffers from incorrect application of computing terms. Volume Shadow Copy Service is available on **all** OSes from Windows XP and up. Only the IT part is unavailable on non-enterprise level OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Wikipedia entry [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system) and was able to find a Windows XP application [here](http://www.acertant.com/web/versomatic/default.htm)

Comment: Ehrm not exactly FLOSS, right?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED You're absolutely right. Perhaps I will start an  FLOSS project to try to put this functionality together.